# Reading the output of windows batch file from c#

Tags: c#, file, batch-file

I have a requirement where I have to check the size of file using windows batch file and read the output from a c# code

batch-script

```
@echo off
set maximumbytesize=1000
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F  %%a in ('dir /B D:\test_batch_files') do (
  set name=%%a
  set size=%%~za
  if  !size! GTR !maximumbytesize! (
    echo greater
  ) ELSE (
    echo smaller
  )
)
```

c# code to get the output:

```
 Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "D:\\test_batch_files\\GetFileSizeInDirectory.bat";
            //ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BatchScriptPath"].ToString();                   
            p.Start();
            StreamReader myStreamReader = p.StandardOutput;
             myString = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();
```

the output from running the batch should be (running from cmd):

```
smaller
smaller
smaller
greater
smaller
smaller
smaller
smaller
smaller
smaller
```

the output from c#

```
smaller
smaller
smaller
smaller
smaller
smaller
smaller
smaller
smaller
smaller
```

Comment: why do you have to do that in batch? can't you just use pure c# ?

Comment: Both outputs have 10 lines. That means you do not loose anything and receive correctly. Issue is perhaps in your batch.
However, please consider calling ReadToEnd after process is finished.

Comment: @PavPs works fine when running directly,gives incorrect output while trying to read it from c# code.tried ReadToEnd after the process has finsihed but still the incorrect output